# Meteor Server-Only Files and Temporary Downloads

Tags: filesystems, meteor

**In Meteor, are there any folders where I can put a .zip which will *not* be sent to the client?**

**Secondary question: how can I make temporary download links on the app, which self-destruct after a period of time?**

The idea is that only the server will have access to this file. `/server` doesn't seem to work because any files I place in there that are not code are not included in the final bundle.

Comment: Ive not tried it, but try `/.stuff` (anything beginning with a '.' except meteor of course)

Comment: You could add it in a folder above the app "../". And then read from that on the server side using "fs". I guess its not being bundled when you publish then. Maybe its a missing feature.

Comment: @Vindberg the issue is I'm using Heroku's filesystem which has only temporary writes - things that you change will be reverted when the dyno is restarted or replicated to scale.

Comment: @Akshat check the answer I've just posted

Comment: @Vindberg Please check the answer I've just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My Solution - Heroku Filesystem

This is probably not the best solution to this problem - however, to anyone else that needs to have files bundled with the app which cannot be seen by the client, here's how I did it.

Note that deleting the secure files is done *because Heroku does not persist filesystem changes on restart*.

- Place files in a folder named "securefiles" or similar in your `/public` folder.
- These get compiled to a folder named `/static` in the bundle. Note that if you're using the Heroku buildpack, the actual path to the working directory for the server is `/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/`.
- Next, on server start, detect if the app is bundled or not. You can do this by checking for the existence of the `static` folder, and there's probably other files unique to a bundle as well.
- If you're bundled, copy the files out of public using `ncp`. I've made a meteorite package just for this purpose, use `mrt add ncp` to add the node copy tool to your project. I recommend copying to the root directory of the app, as this is not visible to clients.
- Next, delete the folder from `static`.

At this point you have files which can only be accessed by the server. Here's some sample coffeescript to do this:

```
Meteor.startup ->
   fs = __meteor_bootstrap__.require 'fs'

   bundled = fs.existsSync '/app' #Checking /app because on heroku app is stored in root / app
   rootDir = if bundled then "/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/" else "" #Not sure how to get the path to the root directory on a local build, this is a bug
   if fs.existsSync rootDir+"securefiles"
       rmDir rootDir+"securefiles"
   #Do the same with any other temporary folders you want to get rid of on startup

   #now copy out the secure files
   ncp rootDor+'static/securefiles', rootDir+'securefiles', ()->
       rmdir rootDir+'static/securefiles' if bundled
```

### Secure/Temporary File Downloads

<sub>Note this code has dependencies on the `random` package and my package `ncp`</sub>

It's very easy to add on to this system to support temporary file downloads, as I have done in my project. Here's how, run `url = setupDownload("somefile.rar", 30)` to create a temporary file download link.

```
setupDownload = (dlname, timeout) ->
    if !timeout?
        timeout = 30
    file = rootDir+'securefiles/'+dlname
    return '' if !fs.existsSync file
    dlFolder = rootDir+'static/dls'
    fs.mkdirSync dlFolder if !fs.existsSync dlFolder
    dlName = Random.id()+'.rar' #Possible improvement: detect file extension
    dlPath = dlFolder+'/'+dlName
    ncp file, dlPath, () ->
        Fiber(()->
            Meteor.setTimeout(() ->
                fs.unlink dlPath
            , 1000*timeout)
        ).run()
    "/dls/"+dlName
```

Perhaps I will make a package for this. Let me know if you could use something like that.